# How to console id from JSON objects using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to get the id's from JSON array like `{id: 123456}`. but i couldn't able to get in this way.

here is a some JSON data:

```
 var categoryArray = [
      {id: '1', name: 'Category_1'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Category_2'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Category_3'},
      {id: '4', name: 'Category_4'}
     ];
```

when i console res.data then it is showing {id: ......} but when i do res.data.id it is showing as undefined. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: That seems impossible, sure it shows  {id: ......} and not [{id: ......}] ?

Comment: @Jon - But i want only ids

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you want to have ?

Comment: @YanvegHD - i could get only one id when i conole `res.data[0]. id` for 1 object. but i want  whole ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have multiple ids, so you have to iterate through the array and you can print all ids. You can use `map` do achieve that:

```
res.data.map(el => console.log(el.id));
```

To get all the ids as you want:

```
const allIds = res.data.map(el => { return {id: el.id} })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the array.

Example:

```
categoryArray.forEach(val => console.log(val.id));
```